# How to return a java type for a specific oracle type using JDBC?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am looking for a solution to returning Java type based on Oracle type. I am using JDBC to connect to the database. I was trying to use `ResultSetMetadata` but it is working strange in my opinion.
For example:

```
create table TMP (
    ID NUMBER(10) not null primary key,
    CODE NUMBER(19,4),
    NAME VARCHAR2(255 char)
)

var query = "SELECT * FROM TMP";
var statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
rsmd.getColumnClassName( 1 ); // ---> java.math.BigDecimal
rsmd.getColumnClassName( 2 ); // ---> java.math.BigDecimal
rsmd.getColumnClassName( 3 ); // ---> java.lang.String
```

As you can see for NUMBER(19,4) ResultSetMetadata is showing "BigDecimal". I would prefer "float" or "double". I think for every "number" it is just "BigDecimal".
Anyone have any idea how to solve that problem? Or am I just forced to write my own method that returns the type of my choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using floating point types like `float` or `double` would be inappropriate for exact numeric types like `NUMBER(19,4)` as it could lead to loss of precision. `java.math.BigDecimal` is also an exact numeric type, and is therefor the type defined by the JDBC Specification mapping of exact numeric types.

You cannot override or configure this, so if you want to apply a different mapping, you need to write that yourself.